# Weird errors with Catalog -> Products adminhtml page on 2.4.3-p2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I am getting this error with Magento 2.4.3-p2, and only in development (Docker).

When I go to the Admin UI page for Catalog -> Products, I get the following error:

[image: screenshot of page where Magento says "Something went wrong."]

Looking at the AJAX call that failed, I see some bizarre parameter handling:

> https://myhost/admin/mui/index/render/key/hash/?namespace=product_listing&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&filters[placeholder][]=true&sorting[field]=thumbnail&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&sorting[direction][]=false&search[]=scsr&search[]=&search[]=&search[]=&search[]=&search[]=&keywordUpdated=false&paging[pageSize]=20&paging[current]=1&isAjax=true

In `exception.log`, I see the following error:

```
Array to string conversion in /app/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Filters/Type/Search.php
```

That is, Magento is expecting the search parameter to be a string, not an array as built up on this page. If I fix that, I get an error for the sorting direction.

It is like my HTML or JS is out of date with the application code. But the static assets are freshly generated and I have confirmed that my Magento UI package version is correct, and the same as on my cloud staging site (which does not have this error). Has anyone seen anything like this, or might know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below shows you the record that you product grid is using to produce the backend screen you see in your Product Catalog.

```
select * from ui_bookmark where namespace='product_listing' and identifier='current'\G
```

[image]

to remove the error, you can remove this line in ui_bookmark (please backup your database before changing data on production environment of course).

to resolve the problem, it is more intricate. You may have installed a module recently, or performed a change. What you are looking for is some code that changes the product listing grid query commonly using data that are custom.

If you really have no idea, the old method is just to disable one module at a time. and checking if the error has gone after each attempt.